# Zend translated routes

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have multiple routes for different locales:

Example:

Route for /de

```
$routes['industry'] = array(
    'route' => 'branche/:type',
    'defaults' => array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'branche',
        'type' => 'automobil'
    ),
    'reqs' => array(
        'type' => '(automobil|textil)'
    )
);
```

Route for /en

```
$routes['industry'] = array(
    'route' => 'industry/:type',
    'defaults' => array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'branche',
        'type' => 'car'
    ),
    'reqs' => array(
        'type' => '(car|textile)'
    )
);
```

Its possible somehow to have just one route instead of 2 on this case?

Note is not just the route which changes, also the type on the reqs and the default type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the translations here:

https://dasprids.de/blog/2009/04/01/translated-segments-for-standard-route/

Answer (score 1):

I see two different routes there
Usually the internationalisation is on the page but not on the url

Let me be clear, you keep your url and with a parameter in the url you know the language of the page so

```
$routes['industry'] = array(
    'route' => 'industry/:lang/:type',
    'defaults' => array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'branche',
        'type' => 'car',
        'lang' => 'en'
    ),
    'reqs' => array(
        'lang' => '(en|de)',
        'type' => '(car|textile)'
    )
);
```

and depending of the parameter lang you display the correct message on your twig or phtml or html

Another way to do this changing the url is:

```
$routes['industry'] = array(
    'route' => ':industry/:type',
    'defaults' => array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'branche',
        'type' => 'car',
        'industry' => 'industry'
    ),
    'reqs' => array(
        'industry' => '(industry|branche)',
        'type' => '(car|textile)'
    )
);
```

Comment: That doesn't resolve the URL translation. Will always be "industry" on the URL and not "branche".

Comment: is it mandatory that change the url? in that case you should do two routes. In my experience you always keep your url in one language and change the content depending the language but of course each reality is different and have different needs. if you need change the url too you have to create two routes or industry|branch is a parameter to. I edit the answer to the solution 2